# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException arises

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

May Be it can be a duplicate question, I'm sorry for that. But my problem is not solving.

Below code gives me this exception (java.util.ConcurrentModificationException ) when execution reaches for 2nd time in foreach loop. Even i removed the arraylist object using iterator.

```
@RequestMapping("edit")
public ModelAndView editItemToInvoice(HttpSession session,@RequestParam("itemname")String itemname){

    ArrayList<InvoiceEntities> show=(ArrayList<InvoiceEntities>)session.getAttribute("invoices");

    if(show==null){
        show=new ArrayList<InvoiceEntities>();
    }

    ArrayList<InvoiceEntities> edit=new ArrayList<InvoiceEntities>();

    for(InvoiceEntities itemnam:show){
        if(itemnam.getItemName().equals(itemname)){
            int index=show.indexOf(itemnam);
            edit.add(show.get(index));

            Iterator<InvoiceEntities> iter = show.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                InvoiceEntities getitem=iter.next();
                if(getitem.getItemName().equals(itemname)){
                    iter.remove();
                    //break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    System.out.println(session.getAttribute("invoices"));

    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView();
    session.setAttribute("invoices", show);
    model.addObject("editobj",edit);
    model.addObject("items",session.getAttribute("invoices"));
    model.setViewName("jsp/Invoice");

    return model;
}
```

Exception is  java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context with  
 path [/Invoice] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested 
 exception is java.util.ConcurrentModificationException] with root cause
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at   mine.Controllers.InvoiceContorller.editItemToInvoice(InvoiceContorller.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
```

Comment: I applied that solution you can see that i'm using iterator to remove the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(InvoiceEntities itemnam:show)
```

creates behind the scene an iterator of `show`, then inside the for loop you create another iterator:

```
Iterator<InvoiceEntities> iter = show.iterator();
```

and use the second iterator to modify `show` by calling `iter.remove();` while the first iterator is still iterating the same collection.

See the paragraph that starts with "For example" in the documentation of [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

When you perform

`iter.remove();`

you are modifying the collection while iterating on it ***with a different*** iterator. `ArrayList` doesnt allow that.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a Fail-Fast iterator collection. So, you should not modify it while iterating it. So, make sure it as you 're trying to remove an item from the list in your code.